# "Can't Connect to This Network" on windows 10, over two iphones

Tags: windows, windows-10, iphone, hotspot

I have two iPhones with mobile data set up as hotspots (different SSID and password).  As I start my Windows 10 computer I can connect to any of them without problem, but as some time passes, if I try to switch from one conection to the other, ERROR apears. If I restart it is connected again.

I tried all possibilities here: https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-11-windows-cant-connect-to-this-network-error-fix/

and nothing changes.

Furthermore, most of the solutions ask for restarting, and this is very frustrating having to restart the computer to change from one WiFi to another.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Answer (score 0):

Your mobile phones on a mobile network use their own IP from their ISP and normally double NAT.

This means your other phone is on a very different network (very most likely). This could be a different ISP.

Double NAT often means you need to restart to change to a different double NAT network.

This is normal and nothing to be really concerned about.

If I connect with my iPhone (double NAT) and then later my Wi-Fi and try to print, I cannot connect to the printer. I must restart and then all is well

Comment: Really? can be normal that change from one WIFI to another, (even they are two mobile hotspot) incurr in a computer restart ?

Comment: Just for curiosity, I would like to know more about it. How can I investigate further?

Comment: It is a concern as soon as to restart you need to close all open work and reopen afterwards

Comment: As I noted very different IP addresses often require a restart. Very normal.